# FirebaseUI Sign In with Google in Android dosen't work

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin, firebaseui

FirebaseUI Sign In with Email and Facebook works fine, but if I want to Sign In with Google, after tapping, I have to choose the account, then the spinner starts loading and that's it.

Looked at this [GitHub](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/auth) link and [Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MGJ8IHHPDAY&list=PLZm85UZQLd2SMSl6gUbjodi9gp7zmgUFl&index=4), did everything, but I don't know why it doesn't work.

```
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:0.6.0'

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'


  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_log_in);

    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    if(auth.getCurrentUser() != null){
        Log.i(TAG, "user logged in");

    }else{
        startActivityForResult(AuthUI.getInstance()
                .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                .setProviders(AuthUI.GOOGLE_PROVIDER,AuthUI.FACEBOOK_PROVIDER,AuthUI.EMAIL_PROVIDER)
                .build(),RC_SIGN_IN);

    }

}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN){
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            Log.i(TAG, auth.getCurrentUser().getEmail());

        }else{
            Log.i(TAG, "something went wrong" );
        }
    }else{
        Log.i(TAG, "something went wrong" );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem can occur if you have not added the project's SHA1 fingerprint to the Project Settings at the Firebase Console.  If you have not done that, add the SHA1 fingerprint and download the `google-service.json` file again.

There is more discussion of this problem at [FirebaseUI-Android Issue 182](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/182).

Comment: Finally found my problem, SHA1 was correct and added to console but i noticed that, my Web API key in firebase console dosen't match with my downloaded json file API key, so i changed my json APi key same to firebase console Web API key. Reason is that i think, i started my project with windows os, but now i am using linux.